# Docker Installation Failure on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, docker

I have hyper-v enabled, thou Docker for Windows installer should enable required Windows features.

Every time I try to install Docker on this Windows 10 pro computer it results in the exception below. I thought of other option like installing Docker on WSL then realized that Docker daemon can not run directly in WSL, but can interact with Docker for Windows

```
Installation Failed

The flat name of the target computer could not be retrieved (2138).
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.LoadComputerInfo()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.get_MachineUserSuppliedName()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.FindNativeByNT4IdentRef(Type principalType, String urnValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SAMStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
   at CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction.<DoAsync>b__33_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Starting Windows service ‘Workstation’ should fix this.
*Seems it’s required only for installation.*: https://forums.docker.com/t/install-fails-on-windows-10/87888

**Starting the `Workstation` service:**

Open CMD as an Administrator and run the command:

```
net start workstation
```

https://www.windows-commandline.com/start-or-stop-workstation-service-from/